# Vertical align text next to image in rhead without influencing the positioning of lhead

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

I try to vertical align a text next to an image in a fancyhdr environment. This is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\headheight=60pt
\lhead{Foo bar \\
    Baz lorem \\
    ipsum dolor}
\chead{}
\rhead{This should be vertically aligned (middle) \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{wappen}}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{titlestyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\Large \today}
}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

It somehow works (the text is vertically aligned), but the multi-lined text on the left is influenced: Its baseline is also shifted upwards.

How can I vertically align the text on the right without modifying the baseline of the left header?

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with the `\Centerstack` command, from the `stackengine` package.

Here is how, with one of my own images since you didn't provide one. Also, centring text w. r. t. the image  is better if you lower of `0.4\height`, to take into account the height of the line of text (the exact value depend on the height of the image, of course):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\headheight=60pt
\lhead{%
\Centerstack[l]{Foo bar \\
    Baz lorem \\
    ipsum dolor}}
\chead{}
\rhead{This should be vertically aligned (middle) \raisebox{-.4\height}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.16]{Hedgehog-in-the-Fog}}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{titlestyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\Large \today}
}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Put everything in the left field of the header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\headheight}{60pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Foo bar \\
  Baz lorem \\
  ipsum dolor
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \mbox{}\\
  This should be vertically aligned (middle) \\
  \mbox{}
  \end{tabular}\quad
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[height=40pt]{duck}
  \end{tabular}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{titlestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\Large \today}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]