# Alignment/Placement of Text using Fancyhdr

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

I am using a solution provided by **egreg** here: [Vertical align text next to image in rhead without influencing the positioning of lhead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277792/vertical-align-text-next-to-image-in-rhead-without-influencing-the-positioning-o)

I'm extremely new to LaTeX and am working in RStudio to replicate a report that was already made using MS Access. Because I need to replicate a report as closely as possible, I need to be able to provide custom parameters to position/align text within a `\fancyhead` call.

**My question is: How can I provide parameters to control the placement of the text "I want to move this vertically and horizontally" and "I also want to move this, but with different parameters"?**

Any and all insight is appreciated, and many thanks in advance! This will be used in a parameterized report, so I am planning to use the flexibility of R to pass arguments to place text in the header, depending on the specific type of report being made.

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\headheight}{60pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Foo bar \\
  Baz lorem \\
  ipsum dolor
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \mbox{}\\
  \fontsize{8}{16}\selectfont\textbf{I want to move this vertically and horizontally} \\
  \fontsize{11}{16}\selectfont\textbf{I also want to move this, but with different parameters}
  \mbox{}
  \end{tabular}
\quad}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{titlestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\Large \today}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these lines to be positioned at will, I would advise to put them in a `picture` environment rather than a `tabular`. Then you can give the position exactly. I have put `\unitlength=1mm` so that the coordinates are in mm. Choose whatever unit fits you best.
I also added a `.` to show where the reference point (origin) is.

```
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Foo bar \\
  Baz lorem \\
  ipsum dolor
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \put(0,0){.}
    \put(20,5){\fontsize{8}{16}\selectfont\textbf{I want to move this vertically and horizontally}}
    \put(5,-2){\fontsize{11}{16}\selectfont\textbf{I also want to move this, but with different parameters}}
  \end{picture}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for `fancyhdr` and for this solution - it works exactly as I had hoped.